# Why do we recite korbanos for Shabbos and Rosh Chodesh but not festivals before psukei dzimra in shacharis?

Tags: tefilla, korbanos-ketores-prayers

During our recitation of korbanos in shacharis we add pesukim from Torah pertaining to the Shabbos korbanos on Shabbos and the Rosh Chodesh korbanos on Rosh Chodesh.

Why do we not also recite korbanos pertaining to any given festival during that festival as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verses for shabbat are recited as they will not be read later as part of the Torah reading.

The verses for Rosh Chodesh are read to publicize that today is Rosh Chodesh.

Neither of these reasons apply to the festivals, so their verses are not read.

Source; Shulchan Aruch and Rema, Orach Chayim 48:1

Comment: Actually, the former reason applies to the Rosh Chodesh verses on Rosh Hashana.